# What are some possible causes of mmc0: error -22

Tags: embedded, sd-card

I'm trying to use an SD card on an embedded linux system. I'm getting this error and I'm hoping someone can tell me what potential problems this error is referring too. I assume the error number can be referenced to the [unix error codes](http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html) Which means 'invalid argument' What could this be in reference too?

```
mmc0: error -22 whilst initialising SDIO card
```

Comment: Has an SD card ever worked with this device and OS?

Answer (score 2):

mmc0: error -22 whilst **initialising** SDIO card

The mmc could not be initialized for a few reasons:

- The wrong or no module is loaded for your embedded device.
- The device tree settings could be wrong for your mmc specs.
- The hardware bus is not ready to tx/rx data.

I get this error on my device when I do not power down correctly. To fix it I do mmcinfo and other mmc commands in u-boot.

In my instance I think there is some µP state not getting reset between the bus and the mmc.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today and the solution was to use a different SD->microSD card adapter. Apparently, there were some incompatibility issue with the first one.